# Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 flutter

Tags: json, flutter, android-studio, dart, uri

I am currently building a weather app which shows the weather of the place including the humidity temperature and rainfall if any. I am using a GeoLocator and http package and an api for the above in Json format .
I am running into the error :-

```
Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:5348:11)
    at Object._parseJson (http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:50003:19)
    at JsonDecoder.convert (http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:47753:22)
    at JsonCodec.decode (http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:47450:48)
    at Object.jsonDecode (http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:49992:25)
    at networking.NetworkHelper.new.getData (http://localhost:58346/packages/clima/services/networking.dart.lib.js:28:37)
    at getData.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:39230:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:39087:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:34073:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:34633:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:34671:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:34513:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:34536:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:39374:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:39380:13)
    at http://localhost:58346/dart_sdk.js:34887:9
ERROR - 2021-09-20 11:17:14.272015
GET /dart_sdk.js:5348:11
Error thrown by handler.
FormatException: Illegal scheme character (at character 5)
dart_sdk.js:5348:11
    ^

dart:core                                                 _Uri.resolve
package:flutter_tools/src/isolated/devfs_web.dart 514:57  WebAssetServer._resolveDartFile
package:flutter_tools/src/isolated/devfs_web.dart 405:17  WebAssetServer.handleRequest
package:dwds/src/handlers/injector.dart 124:32            DwdsInjector.middleware.<fn>.<fn>

ERROR - 2021-09-20 11:18:08.407487
GET /dart_sdk.js:50003:19
Error thrown by handler.
FormatException: Illegal scheme character (at character 5)
dart_sdk.js:50003:19
    ^

dart:core                                                 _Uri.resolve
package:flutter_tools/src/isolated/devfs_web.dart 514:57  WebAssetServer._resolveDartFile
package:flutter_tools/src/isolated/devfs_web.dart 405:17  WebAssetServer.handleRequest
package:dwds/src/handlers/injector.dart 124:32            DwdsInjector.middleware.<fn>.<fn>
```

My expected output Screen was :-

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs0SQ.jpg)

Here is my Code

Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/screens/loading_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: LoadingScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Loading_Screen.dart

```
import 'package:clima/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import '../services/networking.dart';
import 'location_screen.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
const APIkey = '9f2********************';
class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}
double MyMarginAsDouble;
double latitude,longitude;
class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
void initState(){//if i call getlocation inside init maethod it automatically gets the location without the need of a button
  super.initState();
  getLocationData();
}
  Future<void> getLocationData()
  async {
    location ob= new location();
   await ob.getCurrentLocation();
   latitude = ob.latitude;
   longitude = ob.longitude;
   print(ob.latitude);
   print(ob.longitude);

   //calling networkHelper
   NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper('http//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$latitude&lon=$longitude&appid=$APIkey');
 var WeatherData = await networkHelper.getData();
 print(WeatherData);
 Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context){
   return LocationScreen();
 }
 ));
  }
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold();
}
}
```

Location.dart

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class location{
  double latitude;
  double longitude;
  Future<void> getCurrentLocation()
  async {
    try{
      LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low); //high is battery consuming
      LocationPermission permission1 = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
      latitude=position.latitude;
      longitude=position.longitude;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      print(e);
    }
  }

}
```

Networking.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
class NetworkHelper {
  NetworkHelper(this.url);
  var url;
  Future getData() async {
    //var url = Uri.parse(url);
    //var url = Uri.parse('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=92e46************');
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);
return decodedData;
    }
    else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
}
```

Location_screenn.dart

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/utilities/constants1.dart';

class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}

class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
  @override
  Future<void> getLocation()
  async {
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position);
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/location_background.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8), BlendMode.dstATop),
          ),
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.near_me,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.location_city,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      '32°',
                      style: kTempTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '☀️',
                      style: kConditionTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                child: Text(
                  "It's  time in San Francisco!",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  style: kMessageTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


//var weatherData = networkHelper.getData();
//var weatherid = jsonDecode(response.body)['weather'][0]['id'];
//var temp = jsonDecode(response.body)['main']['temp'];
//var name = jsonDecode(response.body)['name'];
```

Comment: Seems like you are not getting an error from the server. Could  you log the response body using: print(response.body) and update your question?

Comment: Is dart_sdk.js really a Json file? From the name, it is not, so you're trying to read a wrong file format.

Comment: @MidhunMP 
{"coord":{"lon":77.5578,"lat":12.922},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":302.94,"feels_like":305.4,"temp_min":301.29,"temp_max":303.18,"pressure":1013,"humidity":59},"visibility":6000,"wind":{"speed":2.06,"deg":240},"clouds":{"all":40},"dt":1632121949,"sys":{"type":2,"id":2032888,"country":"IN","sunrise":1632098334,"sunset":1632142064},"timezone":19800,"id":6695236,"name":"Kanija Bhavan","cod":200}

Comment: @KarthikKK Is this the actual output from the API response?

Comment: Seems like you are getting a server error in an HTML page.  Tags in HTML pages can cause the error. Check the response using a browser or a postman

Comment: @Midhun MP yess this is the actual output

Comment: @NirmalCode I will check once again thanks:)